# How to round specific face with modifier(non-destructively)?

Tags: bevel

I want to round only top/bottom corners with a modifier. But I can't do it with bevel modifier.

Here are the gif processes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Fdi.jpg

Is there a way?

Comment: Seems like the gif is pretty clear. Why don't you add a screenshot of what you're trying to do that shows why it's not working for you.

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Set an Edge Bevel Weight on the target edges, and use 'Weight' rather than 'Angle' as the modifier's Limit method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can select the edges you want to bevel, give them *Bevel Weigh*t in the *N* panel, then in the *Bevel* modifier, choose *Limit Method > Weight* and play with *Offset* and *Segments* values:

[image]

Comment: Thats the answer. Thanks. I tried to boolean that rounded cube out of biger cube, and it gives so random result. One time it extracts, others not. Before the question I tried weight method and it probably worked, but as I didnt see the boolean result I thought it doesnt work. With New models it works like a charm. Though wonder why boolean is so bad. Maybe cuz I use octane version. idk...

Comment: Maybe ask a new queqtion with your problem, boolean should work, but it's not the easiest method to just round corners